# Current rating vs duty cycle

Tags: current, duty-cycle

Is there a rough relationship between the current rating of a device, say a connector, and the duty cycle? For example, I assume a connector rated at a continuous 5 amps isn't necessarily going to be able to cope with 10 amps peak at 50% duty cycle?

Edit: E.g. an ignition coil with a primary resistance of 0.5 ohms would draw 24 amps at 12V. However, at 6000RPM, it's effectively a saw tooth with a 4ms duration. The RMS voltage of which is 6.2V so is that sufficient to calculate current requirements?

Comment: For one thing, 10 A produces 4x the self-heating of any wires or resistive contacts in the connector, not 2x.

Comment: Is reliability important?

Answer (score 3):

Unless such a relationship is given on the datasheet you can't make any assumptions about increasing the current at a low duty cycle.

Many failure modes of electronic devices are accelerated by high temperature, and in those cases it might be acceptable to specify an **average** power consumption or to allow for higher currents at low duty cycles. However, even if this is possible you still need to understand the thermal characteristics of the device...just saying "low duty cycle" might not be sufficient...the manufacturer may specify a maximum **pulse width** at that low duty cycle.

Ultimately, only the manufacturer knows why they have specified a particular current limit. It's possible that a device will be destroyed if you exceed the specified current limit by 20% for 100ns. If it's not in the datasheet then we just don't know.

Comment: "20% for 100ns" -- well...  You can often sorta-kinda guess, although I agree that it's better if the manufacturer has data.  If the pulse repetition rate is well within the shortest thermal time constant in the part, then you just need to hold the average thermal input to the rated value; for a resistive part like a connector, that means keeping the RMS current below the rating.